# how to assign a character to a string at some index which already holds an integer value in python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

This is the code, i'm getting error:

```
a[i] = a[i][:j] + 'X' + a[i][j+1:]
```

where i want to change the value of a string

```
n = int(input())
a = [0 for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    a[i] = input()

for i in range(n):
    if i == 0 or i == (n-1):
        print(a[i])
    else:

        for j in range(1, n-1):
            if (int(a[i][j-1] < int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i][j+1]) < int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i-1][j]) < int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i+1][j]) < int(a[i][j])):
                a[i] = a[i][:j] + 'X' + a[i][j+1:]
        print(a[i])
```

INPUT:

```
4
1112
1912
1892
1234
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
1112
1X12
18X2
1234
```

but getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CavityMap.py", line 10, in <module>
    if(int(a[i][j-1])<int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i][j+1])<int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i-1][j])<int(a[i][j]) and int(a[i+1][j])<int(a[i][j])):
Value Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X'
```

Comment: `int(a[i-1][j])` is going back one row to where you have already inserted the `'X'`.

Comment: but that's not the error. i'm getting error when i'm trying to insert 'X' the first time itself

Comment: Yes, it is. You are trying to convert that 'X' to an integer which raises the error that you see.

Comment: i want to change 1912 to 1X12

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, basing from your example, once you are in the third line

```
1112
1912
1892 <- When you are finally here
1234
```

The second line is already `1X12`. So, `a[]` now looks like

```
1112
1X12 # Take note of the 'X' here.
1892
1234
```

So, when you reach `...and int(a[i-1][j]) < int(a[i][j]) and...` part of the conditional statement, `a[i-1][j]` would be returning `'X'`. Now, since `'X'` is a literal (an alphabetical character), it cannot be type casted to an integer using `int()`. You would need to use `ord()` to convert a character to its representative integer (i.e. `ord('a')` returns `97`) but that will not give the proper results.

---

One solution, from the top of my head, to solve this is to use two arrays. The first array (let's call it array `A`) will contain all the values entered by the user and is not to be modified. Array `A` will be used to compare the characters in each element. The second array (array `B`) will be used to contain the modified values. In other words, array `B` will have the values that have `X`s. The code will look similar to your initial code but with a few changes to include the additional array.

```
n = int(input())
a = [0 for i in range(n)]  # This array will not be modified nor printed. This
                           # will be used for comparisons only.
b = [0 for i in range(n)]  # This array will be used to store the modified values and
                           # be the one printed instead.

for i in range(n):
    a[i] = input()
    b[i] = a[i]  # Here, we're duplicating the values from a[] to b[].

for i in range(n):
    if i == 0 or i == (n - 1):
        print(a[i])
    else:
        for j in range(1, n - 1):
            if (int(a[i][j - 1]) < int(a[i][j])
                and int(a[i][j + 1]) < int(a[i][j])
                and int(a[i - 1][j]) < int(a[i][j])
                and int(a[i + 1][j]) < int(a[i][j])):
                b[i] = a[i][:j] + 'X' + a[i][j + 1:]
        print(b[i])
```